# Knapsack Dynamic Programming - Need help on problem (Roller Coaster Fun)

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I recently started learning Dynamic Programming, and am currently trying to solve ["Roller Coaster Fun" on Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/problems/rollercoasterfun). However, I'm only getting 10/30 test cases (wrong answer on test case 11), and am stuck on what I am doing wrong.

My thinking is very similar to the coin problem ([7.1 in the CPH, scroll down to "Coin Problem"](https://usaco.guide/CPH.pdf#page=75)), where we find the answer for each of the 25,000 times using the previous ones:

(this is pseudocode)

```cpp
// fun[i] is the maximum amount of fun possible at time i
// k[i][j] is the number of times Jimmy goes on coaster j at time i
// all other functions/variables are as given in the problem

fun[1] = 0
fun[n] = max(fun[n - 1], // last fun value (don't go on any new ride)
             fun[n - t[0]] + f(0, k[n][0]),
             ..., 
             fun[n - t[i]] + f(i, k[n][i]), 
             ..., 
             fun[n - t[N - 1]] + f(N - 1, k[n][N - 1]))
```

Here is my full code:

```cpp
// https://open.kattis.com/problems/rollercoasterfun

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_N 100
#define MAX_T 25000

vector<int> a(MAX_N), b(MAX_N), t(MAX_N);

vector<int> dp(MAX_T + 1);
vector<vector<int>> k(MAX_T + 1, vector<int>(MAX_N));

int f(int time, int i)
{
  return max(0, a[i] - k[time][i] * k[time][i] * b[i]);
}

int main()
{
  int N;
  cin >> N;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    cin >> a[i] >> b[i] >> t[i];

  dp[0] = 0;
  fill(k[0].begin(), k[0].end(), 0);

  for (int time = 1; time <= MAX_T; ++time)
  {
    dp[time] = dp[time - 1];
    k[time] = k[time - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
      if (time - t[i] >= 0)
      {
        int newFun = dp[time - t[i]] + f(time - t[i], i);
        if (newFun > dp[time])
        {
          dp[time] = newFun;

          k[time] = k[time - t[i]];
          ++k[time][i]; // go on this ride one more time
        }
      }
    }

    // cout << time << ' ' << dp[time] << '\n';
  }

  int Q;
  cin >> Q;

  int q;
  for (int i = 0; i < Q; ++i)
  {
    cin >> q;
    cout << dp[q] << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See if you can trick the judge into revealing there test case. Then you can step through the data set in your debugger and see what went wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 I couldn't find a way to get the judge test data, but I did some research and found this was from GCPC 2012, and I found the test data on [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://gcpc.nwerc.eu/*) (go to 2nd page and scroll to files with "2012" in them). However, the test data is way too big to actually debug, so I decided to try and see if anyone else knew the answer before attempting to stress test.